# Javascript Mongoose Database 'Doubling' (REST API - Weird)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

I'm new to Javascript and I'm having a recurring error with a REST API. It's a strange error (for me at least), so strange that I don't know what to call it.  I'm calling it "Doubling", but it probably has a proper name, I just don't know what it is.

Anyway, the situation is this.  I'm creating a REST API about cars.  I'm using Javascript and the following node modules:

1) Express
2) Body-Parser
3) Mongoose
4) MongoDB
5) Mongod

The DB is very simple.  It literally just lists the names of cars.  Here's the code for it:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var theAutos = require('./cardata');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/car_test_project', {
  useMongoClient: true,
});

promise.then(function(db){
  console.log('DATABASE NOW CONNECTED!!');
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log('CONNECTION ERROR', err);
});



//*****SCHEMA*****

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var carTestSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
});


var Car = mongoose.model('Car', carTestSchema);

//*****END SCHEMA*****



//*****CAR DATA 'FOR EACH' FUNCTION*****

theAutos.forEach(function(theAutos){
 var newAutomobile = new Car(theAutos);
 newAutomobile.save(function (err) {
     if (err) {
       return (err);
     }
   });
   });

//*****END 'FOR EACH' FUNCTION*****



//******THE 'GET' CODE*****

app.get('/carurl', function(req, res){
  console.log(3);
  Car.find({}).exec(function(err, car){
    console.log(2);
    if(err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    return res.json(car);
  });
});

//******END THE 'GET' CODE*****



//*****POST COMMAND CODE*****

app.post('/carurl', function(req, res){
  var addAnAuto = new Car(req.body);
  addAnAuto.save(function(err, car) {
    if(err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    return res.status(201).json(car);
  });
});

//*****END POST COMMAND CODE*****

app.listen(8000, function(){
  console.log('I be listening!');
});
```

At the beginning, the DB only has one entry; Ferrari.  I've put this in a separate file called `cardata.js` and then I 'require' that file in the 3rd line of the above code (that's what the `var theAutos = require('./cardata');` refers to.  Here's the code for that file:

```
module.exports = [
  {name: "Ferrari"}
]
```

As you can see, very simple database with only one entry.  Now, here's where things get WEIRD!

I go to Postman and make a GET request.  Postman comes back with Ferrari.  So far so good.  Then I go to make a POST request.  I ask for a second car to be added to the database, in this case a Bugatti.  I make a *second* GET request and I see:

```
 {
        "_id": "123etc...",
        "name": "Ferrari",
        "__v": 0
    }

 {
        "_id": "xyzetc...",
        "name": "Bugatti",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

So it's adding Bugatti to the database.  That's great, right?  It's doing what it's supposed to.

Wrong!

See, I need to make sure the addition is permanent, right?  So I go to my terminal and restart the database by typing `node index.js`.  I then go back to Postman and make yet *another* GET request.  I'm *expecting* to see just Ferrari and Bugatti, right?  *However* what I actually see, is:

```
 {
        "_id": "123etc...",
        "name": "Ferrari",
        "__v": 0
    }

 {
        "_id": "xyzetc...",
        "name": "Bugatti",
        "__v": 0
    }


 {
        "_id": "123etc...",
        "name": "Ferrari",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

WTF?!?  Where did that extra Ferrari come from?  *I* certainly didn't want it there.  It's like the DB is loading the DB with my POST request and then loading the original DB (which just had Ferrari in it) on top!  Hence "Doubling"

Now, you might be thinking, "Shank, you fool!  Just use a drop command like `Car.collection.drop();` to refresh the DB when you reload it!"

Trouble is, when I try that I lose my Bugatti!

What I need is to figure out a way to (a) Add my Bugatti and other cars to the database and (b) do so in such a way that when I restart the database it doesn't "Double" and add another Ferrari in there.

It's no exaggeration to say I'm absolutely DESPERATE for help at this point.  I've been grappling with this for days and I've read countless online tutorials and I've not come up with ANYTHING that can help me.

Any advice you could give would be massively appreciated.

Cheers,

Shank.

Comment: *"t the beginning, the DB only has one entry; Ferrari. I've put this in a separate file called .."* - So to make this short and sweet, you have code that inserts this into the database when you start your application, yes? This is why you included it as an exported variable in your code. So what do you think happens each time the application starts? It's **NOT** "doubling". Instead it's **Adding the data to the collection every time you restart**. Simple evidence is the actual `_id` is different in your real data, and not what you present here.

Comment: So how do I fix it?  I'm given to understand that most devs keep their database in a separate file and include it as an exported variable.  What are they doing that I'm not doing?

Comment: If you are "seeding" on startup then what you do is "remove" the previous data before you insert the "working set". Apparent I'm not "most devs" as the only time I "seed" is with specific tooling calls or with "unit tests", rather than an arbitrary block of code that always runs on server startup. The main point here is your "question" does not actually include the code that is doing this. You merely "mention" it in the statement I highlighted. Rambling sentences **do not** show us what your code is doing. Your **actual code** does.

Comment: I've included every piece of code that I've written on this project. I'm showing you everything I've written, in every file. And I'm a BEGINNER.

Comment: Her'es the base points, choose which applies to you. 1. Live with "seed" data **only** and drop the content before you "seed". 2. Learn what ["upserts"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) are, and basically "create or update" the "seed" items, leaving other data intact. Option 2 even allows you to [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) and thus "ignore" when data is matched and already exists.